# custom EAV model saving attributes

Tags: attributes, database, eav

I have a custom EAV model that uses custom tables for comments that can be set on either products or categories. I have created an admin for these using the standard EAV admin form.

In my controller, I have a save action:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        try {
            $model = Mage::getModel('module/comment');
            $model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
            $model->save();

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('module')->__('The comment has been saved.'));

            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit',
                array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('module')->__('There was an error saving the comment'));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

When I save the form with a new comment, the grid page shows the new comment. But, when I look in the database with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_comment_text WHERE entity_id = 1;
```

I see the following:

```
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value                   |
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
|        1 |             31 |          964 |        0 |         1 | test                    |
|        4 |             31 |          964 |        0 |         1 | test adding another one |
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Can anyone explain why (a) Magento does not replace the existing value and (b) how Magento knows which one to show in the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: you need a unique index on the following combination of columns: `entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`.

**Long answer:**

On an EAV entity (let's take products for example) your table could never look like that.
You have 2 records for the same combination of `attribute_id | store_id | entity_id`.
On the product tables (`catalog_product_entity_varchar` for example but it's the same for `_int` and others) there is a unique constraint on these 3 columns.

```
UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),
```

This is created in the install script (see `install-1.6.0.0.php`)

```
->addIndex(
    $installer->getIdxName(
        array('catalog/product', 'varchar'),
        array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
        Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
    ),
    array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
    array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE))
```

And when saving an attribute value (insert or update) a call to the method `insertOnDuplicate` is made.
This method tries to insert the values you provide to it and if there is a unique key duplicate it just updates the values you specify. In the case of the EAV tables only the `value` field is updated.
Since you don't have that unique constraint on the table it just inserts an other row.
Try adding that constraint and I have a feeling the problem will go away.

Comment: awesome! that was driving me nuts... :)